# List is a raw type. Reference to generic type List <E> should be parameterized

Tags: java

anyone knows how to fix this error?
Here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/eki8cn

```
    <%Iterator<String> itr;%>

    <%List data = (List)request.getAttribute("InventoryData");
    for(itr = data.iterator(); itr.hasNext();){ 
    %>
    <tr>
        <%String s = (String) itr.next();%>
        <td>
            <%=s%>
        </td>
```

Comment: `List<String> data = (List<String>)` ?

Comment: I am having errors on the..
3rd and 4th line..
Here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/eki8cn

Comment: did you change the code as I told you?

Comment: I enter the new line.
<%List<String> data = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("InventoryData");
This is what I got: http://prntscr.com/ekibw1

Comment: Hello sir @borowis
May I know how to display the items on the table?
Here is a screenshot of my code: http://prntscr.com/ekitpk

Comment: you should ask another question for that. your code looks good to me, td is a cell, tr is a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List` interface you are using is not parameterized to hold `String` values.

Replace it will `List<String>` everywhere and it should work fine.

You can also simplify it further.  You don't need to declare the `Iterator` too.

So your code becomes this:

```
<%List<String> data = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("InventoryData");
for(String s: data) { 
%>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%=s%>
    </td>
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: <%List<String> data = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("InventoryData");

http://prnt.sc/ekibw1

Comment: Yeah, what about it?

Comment: sir I am getting "Type safely: Unchecked cast from Object to List<String>" on the same line [here is a screenshot](http://prnt.sc/ekibw1) @anacron

Comment: Hello sir @anacron
May I know how to display the items on the table?
Here is a screenshot of my code: http://prntscr.com/ekitpk

Comment: See if you can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before the `List<String> data` declaration.

Comment: Oh! I see you've already added that.

Comment: that workss thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!